$A \subseteq B$ integral extension of domains, $m \subset A$ maximal ideal, then $mB \neq B$.

$A \subseteq B$ integral extension of domains, $m \subset A$ maximal
ideal, then $mB \neq B$.

My try:
As $m$ is maximal in $A$, then $k:=A/m$ is a field, and as $mB$ is an ideal of $B$, consider the group $M:=B/mB$. 
Affirmation: $M$ is a $k$ vector space with the product defined by $$(a+m)(b+mB):=ab+mB.$$
For simplicity write $\overline{a}\overline{b}=\overline{ab}$.
Problem : If we take $b \in B$, there is a monic irreducible polynomial such that
$$b^n+a_{n-1}b^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1b+a_0=0$$
since the extension is integral.
So for a fixed elements $b \in B$ the powers $b^k$ with $k\geq n$ vanish. I was trying to do the same method that the one we use to prove that $$K[x]/(f(x))$$ is a $K$ vector space with basis $\{1,x, \ldots ,x^{deg(f)-1} \}$ for $f$ irreducible polynomial, but is different because we may think that $M_k\cong(\overline1,\overline{b},\ldots, \overline{b}^{n-1})$, but if we take another $b' \in B$ the polynomial is different; so I don't know how to keep from here to claim that the dimension of $M$ over $k$ has to be positive.
Because if we have that, we say that $B/mB=M$ is a $0$ dimensional vector space over $k$, that would contradict the possible basis above, any hint to keep working on this idea?

The statement in the title is immediate if you know lying over: Let $\mathfrak q\cap A=\mathfrak m$ where $\mathfrak q$ is a prime ideal of $B$. Then $\mathfrak q\subsetneqq B$ (for otherwise $\mathfrak m=B\cap A=A$), and consequently $\mathfrak mB\subseteq\mathfrak q\subsetneqq B$.

Recall Nakayama's lemma: Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module and $I\subseteq R$ be an ideal such that $IM=M$. Then there exists $r\in I$ such that $(1-r)M=0$.
Now suppose $A\subseteq C$ is an integral extension of domains, and further assume that $C$ is finitely generated as an $A$-algebra. Then it is a standard theorem that $C$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module. Now let $I$ be a proper ideal of $A$. I claim that $IC\neq C$. Suppose not. Then by Nakayama's lemma, there is an $r\in I$ such that $(1-r)C=0$. Since $C$ contains $1$, we get $1-r=0$, i.e. $1=r\in I$, a contradiction.
Finally, let us see how to reduce the general case to the above case. Let $A\subseteq B$ be as in your problem and let $I$ be a proper ideal of $A$. Suppose $IB=B$. Then there exist finitely many elements $r_i\in I$ and $b_i\in B$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n r_ib_i=1$. Consider the ring $C=A[b_1,\ldots,b_n]$. Then $A\subseteq C$ satisfies the hypothesis in the second paragraph. Moreover $IC=C$. But this contradicts above result.
